# How to run VS 2015 cordova app on iPad Pro simulator?

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't list iPad Pro as an available simulator (iPad Retina is the latest), even though it is present in the cordova run.js

Is there a way to run a remote-build cordova app from VS 2015 in the iPad Pro simulator on a Mac as I need to get iPad Pro screenshots of this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround for this issue until Microsoft adds the target.

1. Build your App for iOS Simulator (e.g. iPad Retina)
2. Copy the folder platforms\ios (under your project folder) to your MAC development machine
3. Open (Project).xcodeproj (inside the ios-Folder) in xCode
4. Build your Project for the iPad Pro Simulator and take your screenshots

That did the job for me, hope that helps.

Comment: works for me too. had to delete the old platform\ios to force VS to update